# Using webpack to load CSS files from node modules

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to use a [react component](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/) that includes a css file. I'm requiring the component as usual:

```
var Select = require('react-select');
```

I'd like to know how can I require the css needed for the component.

I've already tried this:

```
require('react-select/dist/react-select.css');
```

And this:

```
require('react-select.css');
```

And none have worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//package.json
"dependencies": {
    "my-package": "2.0.0"
}
//app.js
//Get a relative path to the installed css files:
require('../someRelativePathFromAppJs/node_modules/my-package/somePath/myNeeded.css')
```

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you have the following packages installed:

```
npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev
```

and that your webpack configuration has this:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
  ]
}
```

This will require and bundle any css file that you require, and I would pull their exactly how you did it:

```
require('react-select/dist/react-select.css');
```

Another workaround that works for certain is that you **copy** that css file, and in the html you link it by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/react-select.css">
```

Comment: I have that config on my webpack configuration file

Comment: This is the correct answer, however for newbies like myself - Make sure you then have the style-loader and css-loader plugins installed so webpack can read them.

Comment: @Birksy89 For even newer newbies run this `npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev` and also if you decide to split the CSS into it's own file as per the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html) be sure to remove the explicit css marker in the require as is mentioned [here](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/295#issuecomment-231510027)

Comment: @nmu I am an even newer newbie, and you have saved me from a very, very long day.

Comment: @nmu so you are installing loaders for css and styles just on development and not using CSS in production?

Comment: I am getting this error. Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'font/VideoJS.eot' in /home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/video.js/dist
I have all the file loaders and url loader in place.